# Running Elevated Logon Script

Tags: windows-7, windows, script, powershell, group-policy

I have to run a powershell script every time a user logs on. This script needs to be run elevated. Is there a way to do this with out prompting the user. I am currently running the script using on windows 7 using gpedit.msc

Cheers, --Orlan

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are doing.  I would recommend you download the launchapp.swf program from technet.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766208(WS.10).aspx

It basically uses Task Scheduler to launch your login script, which will launch it using admin creds.